# PHP +CodeIgniter , RestFul Url without MVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would use CodeIgniter in my new project, but i only use the helper function, so
Can i run my php script as CodeIgniter restful Url function but not in MVC?

or i can done by Apache rewrite mod instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache rewrites would be more suitable if you don't have a need to use CodeIgniter.

In your `.htaccess` file you'd use something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [PT]
```

Then you can use `http://yoursite.com/whatever` and `$_GET['page']` will equal `whatever`.